# This error occurred while I am trying to execute this code

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wire, lds

Apex Class:

```
public class updaterec {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void updateContact(String recordId, String firstName, String lastName) {
        Contact contactToUpdate=[Select Firstname,LastName From Contact where Id=:recordId];
        contactToUpdate.FirstName=firstName;
        contactToUpdate.LastName=lastName;
        update contactToUpdate;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Update Contact with the apex ----2">
        <h2>Update Record</h2>
            <lightning-input label="New First Name" value={newFirstName} onchange={handleNewFirstNameChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input label="New Last Name" value={newLastName} onchange={handleNewLastNameChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button label="Update" onclick={updateRecord}></lightning-button>
           
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement,track,api } from 'lwc';
import updateContact from '@salesforce/apex/updaterec.updateContact';
export default class Updaterec extends LightningElement {
@api recordId
@track FirstName;
@track LastName;


handleNewFirstNameChange(event)
{
    this.FirstName=event.target.value;
}
handleNewLastNameChange(event)
{
    this.LastName=event.target.value;
}
updateRecord()
{
   
    updateContact({recordId:this.recordId[1],FirstName:this.FirstName,LastName:this.LastName})
   .then(()=>{
    console.log('update the data');
   })
   .catch(error =>{
    console.log('Update Failed' + error);
   })
}


}
```

It is showing error: 'Update Failed' + error:

[image]

Comment: What is the error print in the console?

Comment: The `cacheable` parameter for the AuraEnabled annotation is for methods that return data to your front end experience. If your method is doing some DML and returning nothing, then you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameter values to an Apex method in an object whose properties match the parameters of the Apex method. For example, if the Apex method takes a string parameter, don’t pass a string directly. Your LWC should pass an object that contains a property whose value is a string instead:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void someMethod(String str) { ... }
```

```js
someMethod({ str: "param" }).then(...)
```

In your code, you have only passed the two-parameter in updateContact, but actually, the apex method contains three parameters. Update your code as below:

```
updateRecord(){
   
    updateContact({recordId: this.recordId, firstName: this.FirstName, lastName: this.LastName})
    .then(()=>{
        console.log('update the data');
    })
    .catch(error =>{
        console.log('Update Failed' + error);
    })
}
```

For more information you can refer to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-call-imperative.html

Answer (score 0):

When calling Apex from your Javascript, the parameters are case-sensitive.

In your Javascript you have `{FirstName:this.FirstName,LastName:this.LastName}`, but in your Apex you have `(String recordId, String firstName, String lastName)`. Amend your Javascript to reference `firstName` and `lastName` instead. You are also missing the `recordId` parameter.

As an aside, you don't need to query the contact you are updating. You can instead do:

```
Contact contactToUpdate = new Contact();
contactToUpdate.Id = recordId;
contactToUpdate.FirstName = firstName;
contactToUpdate.LastName = lastName;
update contactToUpdate;
```

Comment: ok thank you . But let me know how can we do this by querying the fields. that is my doubt.

Comment: you don't need to query the fields because you're not doing anything with them

Answer (score 0):

DML is not allowed if the cacheable=true. So change it to false and try.